# Possible to pass a Foreign Server connection from DB1 to DB2 to run a query on DB2 with that connection?

Tags: postgresql, connection, remote-server, postgresql-9.6

In PostgreSQL 9.6, I'm in one database using a Foreign Server connection. But I have a second database which is a common Db with common functions. I'd like to add a common function to that common db where I can pass in a Foreign Server connection and have that function execute the query on the remote server through DBLINK_CONNECT and DBLINK_SEND_QUERY.

I realize I can physically add the foreign server to the common db, however that would not be practical as I'd have to add a new physical foreign server for every new remote server and that could get out of hand. So I'd rather pass in the connection and use DBLINK_CONNECT to create the connection on the fly rather than use a physical.

Is this possible? I have looked around without luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not, if you pass all the necessary information for dblink? I don't know if that is a sane architecture though. Why not access the databases from the client side?

Comment: The real problem is the password.

Comment: Use some other authentication method like SSL certificates.